# How to remove project name after port number

Tags: jsf

I am developing jsf project. I want to remove project name in URL . I want http://localhost:8080 instead of http://localhost:8080/simpleJSF1/. The problem is in my java code i have to write project name to redirect to another page Like this.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/simpleJSF1/login.xhtml");
```

If i somehow able to to remove project name from url then i can write like this
 `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/login.xhtml");`

instead of 
`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/simpleJSF1/login.xhtml");`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait, you just want to split a string based on a delmiter?

Comment: No, I want when i run project and enter http://localhost:8080 my project should run. Now to run the project i need to enter project name after port number like this http://localhost:8080/simpleJSF1/.    where simpleJSF1 is my project name.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use your context as provided by [ExternalContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) - that way it's neither hard coded nor limited to ROOT-context.

```
FacesContext ctx= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) ctx.getExternalContext().getContext();
ctx.getExternalContext().redirect(
    servletContext.getContextPath() +"/login.xhtml");
```

Comment: Thanks a ton that solve problem. But is there any way to remove project name from URL like http://localhost:8080 to open project directly. I do not want to see project name in URL .

Comment: Deploy it as root webapp (in tomcat ROOT.war )